# perpendicular distance from a straight line to a point

Tags: geometry

I want to find the distance from a point to a straight line, but the formula should be in style $ d=-\sin(\theta)*(x-x_o)+\cos(\theta)*(y-y_o) $.

Hence the problem is that we have to express the parameters A, B and C of an equation with sin and cos only where $\theta$ is the angle that the line forms with horizontal line so $\tan(\theta)$ will be the slope of the line

Comment: What have you tried? Can you at least write down an equation of the line in terms of $\cos\theta$ and $\sin\theta$?

Answer (score 0):

Let a line be defined in $\mathbb{R}^n$ by two points $x_1, x_2 \in \mathbb{R}^n$ as $p(\lambda)=(1-\lambda)x_1 + \lambda x_2 \in \mathbb{R}^n$, where $\lambda \in \mathbb{R}$ and let your point be $q \in \mathbb{R}^n$. The shortest distance from $q$ to $p$ is the projection of $q$ onto $p$. That is, we need to find a $\lambda$ such that $(x_2-x_1) \cdot (p(\lambda) - q) = 0$ (the vector $(x_2-x_1)$ is orthogonal to the vector $(p(\lambda)-q)$). Expanding the expression for $p(\lambda)$ yields: 
$$(x_2-x_1)\cdot(x_1 + (x_2-x_1)\lambda_0-q) = 0$$
And using the distributivity of the dot product:
$$\lambda_0 = \frac{(x_2-x_1)\cdot(q-x_1)}{||x_2-x_1||^2}$$
Then plugging in $\lambda_0$ in $p(\lambda)$ yields:
$$p(\lambda_0) = x_1 + (\hat{d}\cdot(q-x_1))\hat{d}$$
Where $\hat{d} = \frac{x2-x_1}{||x_2-x_1||}$ is the normalized 'direction' vector of the line.
Taking into account that $a\cdot b = ||a||\cos(\angle(a,b))||b||$ you get your forumla for the point expressed throught the cosine between $(q-x_1)$ and $\hat{d}$ and the length of $(q-x_1)$.

Finally the distance is $||p(\lambda_0)-q||$. This can be computed in another way also by using the Pythagorean theorem. Let the angle between $(x_2-x_1)$ and $(q-x_1)$ be denoted as $\theta$, and the length of $(q-x_1)$ be denoted by $l$. Then the projection of $(q-x_1)$ onto $p$ has length $|l\cos\theta|$. Then the distance can be derived from the Pythagorean theorem as: $|l\cos\theta|^2 + h^2 = l^2$, and thus: $h = \sqrt{l^2 - |l\cos\theta|^2} = l|\sin\theta|$.